# Clipping elements in a long vector to +/-threshold

Tags: r, algorithm, clipping

I am writing program in R. I stuck here.

I have  vector like

```
X=c(84.05, 108.04, 13.95, -194.05, 64.03, 208.05, 84.13, 57.04)
```

I want to get a vector after replacing all elements of this vector which are >180 by 180
and all elements which are less than <-180 by -180.

Like I want to get,

```
X=c(84.05, 108.04, 13.95,-180, 64.03, 180, 84.13, 57.04)
```

How to do this??

The vector which I am working is very large.

Comment: This operation is called *clipping* or *clamping*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `pmin`

```
> pmin(abs(X), 180)*sign(X)
[1]   84.05  108.04   13.95 -180.00   64.03  180.00   84.13   57.04
```

**Benchmark**

```
> Jilber <- function() pmin(abs(X), 180)*sign(X)
> MrFlick <- function() pmin(pmax(X, -180), 180)
> user1317221_G <- function() ifelse(X < -180,-180, ifelse(X > 180, 180, X))
> benchmark(replications=50000,
+           Jilber(),
+           MrFlick(),
+           user1317221_G(), 
+           columns=c('test', 'elapsed', 'relative'))
             test elapsed relative
1        Jilber()   0.835    1.000
2       MrFlick()   1.297    1.553
3 user1317221_G()   1.709    2.047
```

Comment: I think i more often see `pmin(pmax(X, -180), 180)`. Do you think this is more efficient?

Comment: Working nicely. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MrFlick, your solution probably is more efficient than mine, I should benchmark. Very nice by the way.

Comment: I think the reason for more efficiency is that, in the first code suggested by @Jilber there are three functions used...where as in the code suggested by MrFlick involves two function. Am I thinking correctly or missing something? Thank you.

Comment: @MrFlick according benchmark results, your alternative is 63% slower than mine.

Comment: Can you also benchmark @user1317221_G's ifelse approach?

Comment: Hmm, nested `ifelse` is so slow, we need three-way ifelse... or `switch()`

Answer (score 1):

```
ifelse(X < -180,-180, ifelse(X > 180, 180, X))
```